# Execute a function on a site which is normally executed by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to execute a function on a site which is normally executed by clicking the button, without clicking the actual button (so either through the console or another way)

site: https://clickthatbutton.com/

As you can see on the site once you click the button it adds a click to this sentence: "7 CLICKS FROM YOU... THANK YOU". I want to run the function that adds 1 click to that sentence without clicking the button or changing the number in elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#click").submit()
```

from the console

Interestingly they should not have called the button "submit"

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find the element you want to target, in this case the id is #submit. Then you can use the native function `click()` on it.

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').click()
```

The website exoses Jquery but this can perfectly be done with native functions.

Comment: Did you try this by the way? It does not show the page again but loads the payload

Comment: Yes, works fine on my side. 
I think it's ok to call the submit button #submit

Comment: I never used to be a good thing since it would hide the submit method. If I run your code in Chrome, I see the new number but do not set the cookie and do not see the screen update

Comment: I have this issue with `document.querySelector('#click').submit()` but not with #submit.click

Comment: yeah but this is exaclty what I didn't want. I want to do it else than ".click" .
Any possible way will help

Comment: What is exactly what you didn't want?